# how to solve this Whitespace issue in python?

Tags: python

(1) Prompt the user to input a food item name, price, and quantity. Output an itemized receipt. (Submit for 5 points)

```
Enter food item name:
hot dog
Enter item price:
2.00
Enter item quantity:
5

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $ 2.0 = $ 10.0
Total cost: $ 10.0
```

(2) Extend the program to prompt the user for a second item. Output an itemized receipt. (Submit for 5 points, so 10 points total)

```
Enter food item name:
hot dog
Enter item price:
2.00
Enter item quantity:
5

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $ 2.0 = $ 10.0
Total cost: $ 10.0


Enter second food item name:
ice cream
Enter item price:
2.50
Enter item quantity:
4

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $ 2.0 = $ 10.0
4 ice cream @ $ 2.5 = $ 10.0
Total cost: $ 20.0
```

(3) Extend again to output a third receipt that adds a mandatory 15% gratuity to the total cost. Output the total cost, the cost of gratuity, and the grand total. (Submit for 5 points, so 15 points total)

```
Enter food item name:
hot dog
Enter item price:
2.00
Enter item quantity:
5

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $ 2.0 = $ 10.0
Total cost: $ 10.0


Enter second food item name:
ice cream
Enter item price:
2.50
Enter item quantity:
4

RECEIPT
5 hot dog @ $ 2.0 = $ 10.0
4 ice cream @ $ 2.5 = $ 10.0
Total cost: $ 20.0

15% gratuity: $ 3.0
Total with tip: $ 23.0
```

My code:

```
item_name = input('Enter food item name:\n')
item_price = float(input('Enter item price:\n'))
item_quantity = int(input('Enter item quantity:\n'))

total_cost = item_price * item_quantity

print("RECEIPT")
print( item_quantity , item_name , '@ $', item_price, '= $', total_cost )
print('Total cost:' , '$' , total_cost)
```

The output says it has white space?

Comment: use string format to while printing  `print(f"Total Cost: $ {total_cost}")`

Comment: In which line it is saying whitespace?

Comment: *"The output says it has white space?"* Is that a question? Please include the output in the question if you're going to mention it.

Answer (score -2):

```
item_name = input('Enter food item name:\n')
item_price = float(input('Enter item price:\n'))
item_quantity = int(input('Enter item quantity:\n'))
print()
print('RECEIPT')
total_cost = (item_price * item_quantity)

print(item_quantity, item_name, '@',f'${item_price:.2f}', '=',f'${total_cost:.2f}')
print('Total cost:',f'${total_cost:.2f}')
print()
print()
item_name2 = input('Enter second food item name:\n')
item_price2 = float(input('Enter item price:\n'))
item_quantity2 = int(input('Enter item quantity:\n'))
print()
print('RECEIPT')
total_cost2 = (item_price2 * item_quantity2)
total_cost3 = (item_price2 * item_quantity2) + (item_price * item_quantity) 
print(item_quantity, item_name, '@',f'${item_price:.2f}', '=',f'${total_cost:.2f}')
print(item_quantity2, item_name2, '@',f'${item_price2:.2f}', '=',f'${total_cost2:.2f}')
print('Total cost:',f'${total_cost3:.2f}')
print()
tip_amt = (total_cost3 * .15)
total_amount_tip = (tip_amt + total_cost3)
print('15% gratuity:',f'${tip_amt:.2f}')
print('Total with tip:',f'${total_amount_tip:.2f}')
```